# How to use sudo tee in GVIM for Windows

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

Can I use something like

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

in GVIM for Windows? Is there any analogue?

Or can I disable UAC for one program only and always run it as administrator?

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult; you can try the [SudoEdit.vim - Edit Files using sudo or su or any other tool](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2709) plugin.

But it's probably easiest to just launch (G)Vim with elevated priviledges itself.

Answer (score 0):

install msys2/cygwin or something include tee.exe and https://github.com/mattn/sudo
Then, do `:w !sudo cmd /c tee %`